# Redirect to login page or landing page if session expire in react with react router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, react-router

In my React App,I need to redirect the current page to landing page if session expires , I am using the

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
```

My session expiration time is 60. I am doing the private routing with following approach,

```
export const getCurrentUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(BASE_URL + GET_CURRENT_USER, { withCredentials: true });
        localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.id);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_CURRENT_USER,
            payload: res.data
        });

        return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
export default function PrivateOutlet() {
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCurrentUser())
        .then((res) => {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            localStorage.setItem('id', res.id);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error) );
    }, [dispatch]);

    return   ( isLoaded ? (localStorage.getItem('id') !== undefined) ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/landingPage" /> : <></>)

};


<Route path="/*" element={<PrivateOutlet />} >
    <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
</Route>
```

By using this approach, if I reload the page it is redirecting to landing page but ,If I  not doing the reload and lets say I trigger any event it is showing nothing since Backend APIs are returning nothing since session has been expired.

So If session expired How I redirect the current page to landing page if I trigger any click or any event?

Comment: Is the backend where the session is being validated? Could it return an error response that your service code could check and handle accordingly, i.e. do the client-side redirect to your authentication route? Does the client store anything related to the session that it could check without waiting for the backend to say a session has been invalidated? What have you tried already?

Comment: Yes Backend is validating the session and the session timeout is 60 if session expired getCurrentUser() is returning nothing..I have tried with the private outlet in routing it is only working if I reload the page then it will redirect to landing page..But If I stay on ant page and session expired then If I open lets say open modal or any button click then it is loader is running

Comment: Are you saying that if the session is expired that `getCurrentUser()` returns nothing, or that it returns a resolved promise and that `res` is undefined? Would showing us the `getCurrentUser` action creator and related Redux code help us understand better?

Comment: I have added the code of the getCurrentUser() action

Comment: My suggestion might be something similar to Alexey's answer, but I see your comment saying that won't work. Can you clarify why this won't work? What instantiates the session? Does the client get a cookie or some other indication a session is established and its expiration?

Comment: I have debugged with console.log() within the useEffect() in PrivateOutlet component. I have seen that it only calling when routing change or page reloading.

Comment: Is there a problem with that? The session will expire and the next navigation to a protected route will check the session. Are you wanting to do something ***earlier*** than the next time `getCurrentUser` is dispatched? If so, then the app will need to know more about the session, like when it'll expire, so it can preemptively do *something*. Does this make sense? Is there a mechanism currently for your app to know about and sessions with the backend?

Comment: There is no mechanism in  my app to know sessions..Now here I question here how I know the session has been expired.Should I use setTimeout here ?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. Ideally the frontend would know when the session *would* expire and set a timeout. It should persist this expiration so when the page is reloaded/etc the app can check the session expiration and re-establish the timeout. Sounds like you need to work on the "knowing the session expiration" part. The alternative is to not worry about the exact expiration and wait for the app to do the next "check-in" and handle it then. One is a bit more work than the other. What are the chances a user sits "idle-ish" on one page more than 60 minutes? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

add state for error:

`const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);`

set error state when result is failed:

`.catch(error => setIsError(true) );`

and before base return with isLoaded check add:

```
if (isError) {
   return <Navigate to="/landingPage" replace={true} />
}
```

Comment: This won't work because , PrivateOutlet is only calling when page is reloading or routing any other page..If session expired then it is not calling..